# Wordpress Shortcode - Add Media Modal

Tags: wordpress, media, shortcode

I'm creating a custom shortcode in WordPress and I'd like to allow the user select or upload some media using the media modal window as part of the process.

What is the best method to invoke the add media modal?

```
function CheesyEmbed_func($atts){

  $atts = shortcode_atts(array(
            'type' => '',
            'source' => ''
        ), $atts);

  if($atts['type'] == 'youtube'){
    $output = "<style>.embed-container { position: relative; padding-bottom: 56.25%; height: 0; overflow: hidden; max-width: 100%; } .embed-container iframe, .embed-container object, .embed-container embed { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; }</style><div class='embed-container'><iframe src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/" . $atts['source'] . "?modestbranding=1&rel=0&showinfo=0&color=white&iv_load_policy=3' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe></div>";
    return $output;
  }

  if($atts['type'] == 'image'){
    $output = "<img src='" . $atts['source'] . "' class='img-responsive'>";
    return $output;
  }
}
add_shortcode('CheesyEmbed','CheesyEmbed_func');
```

Comment: Your shortcode should be replaced with a button in the frontend. On that button click a modal window should popup which should allow user to select image/video. When user does that it should be shown somewhere. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 1):

```
function CheesyEmbed_func($atts){

    $atts = shortcode_atts(array(
        'type' => '',
        'source' => ''
    ), $atts);

    ob_start(); ?>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Media</button>
    <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-body">
    <?php
    $output = ob_get_clean();

    if($atts['type'] == 'youtube'){
        $output .= "<style>.embed-container { position: relative; padding-bottom: 56.25%; height: 0; overflow: hidden; max-width: 100%; } .embed-container iframe, .embed-container object, .embed-container embed { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; }</style><div class='embed-container'><iframe src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/" . $atts['source'] . "?modestbranding=1&rel=0&showinfo=0&color=white&iv_load_policy=3' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe></div>";
    }

    if($atts['type'] == 'image'){
        $output .= "<img src='" . $atts['source'] . "' class='img-responsive'>";
    }

    else{
        $output .= 'No Content Here';
    }

    $output .= '</div></div></div></div>';

    return $output;

}

add_shortcode('CheesyEmbed','CheesyEmbed_func');
```

If you are using Bootstrap the above code should work. If not you can use other methods to fire modal window, and edit the html by using same logic.

You can Add Upload button with type attribute like so:

```
if($atts['type'] == 'upload'){
    $output .= "<form action='somewhere.php'><input id='upload' type='file'><input type='submit' value='Upload'></form>";
}
```

You can handle user's selection with jquery like this:

```
$("#myModal").on("click", "img, iframe", function () {
    //Append this somewhere else in the page.
    //Or upload $atts['source'] value to server. etc
});
$( "#myModal form" ).submit(function(e) {
    //Do something
});
```

Hope that helps. If not feel free to ask!

Comment: Thanks. Do you know how to invoke the WordPress select media modal? http://wpsites.net/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/Media-Library.png

Comment: Yes. you need to trigger `wp.media({...});` on button click. Please refer [documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Javascript_Reference/wp.media).